# Overall Unique count from two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, count

I have two tables, both having column a device_id column that I want to count. For the purposes of demonstration, the schema looks like:

```
Table 1: 'id', 'save_val', 'device_id_major'
Table 2: 'id', 'save_val', 'location', 'device_id_team'
```

Table 1 could have many of the same '`device_id_major`'.

I basically want to get the unique device_id's from both tables, then from that result set, get the count of unique device_id's (the same device_id can appear in both tables).

Is this possible in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT aa.id) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT major_id AS id FROM `major` 
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT team_id AS id FROM `team`) 
AS aa
```

This seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct aa.device_id, count(*) 
from(select distinct device_id from table1
union all
select distinct device_id from table2) as aa
group by device_id
order by device_id
```

Or something like... As I don't have the schema to hand, I can't fully validate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query that takes the UNION of both tables, then SELECT the unique values.

Comment: SELECT count( distinct T.ID) from ( select id from firstT union select id from secondT ) T  . Notice that distinct is not needed because union behavior.

Comment: My schema was a bit wonky - can you restate?